# How to properly update dataset after getting JSON list from server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching JSON array of user ids from a server (not Firebase server).
I also store images of each user in Firebase storage. I have a dataset of Users, that contain user id and user image url. The JSON response is constantly updating, so every call I receive new response from the server with new list of user ids. The only solution I came up with, is to:

Clear dataset > Loop through the JSON Array to add all users to the empty dataset > notify dataset changed.

The problem with this is that it's not efficient: I notify data set changed on each iteration, and also since I clear the dataset every new response (from the remote server), the list refreshes, instead of simply adding / removing the necessary users.

This is how the code looks:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) { // the JSON ARRAY response of user ids ["uid1", "uid334", "uid1123"]
    myDataset.clear(); // clear dataset to prevent duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
            String userKey = response.get(i).toString(); // the currently iterated user id
            final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference userKeyRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userKey); // reference to currently iterated user
            ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                myDataset.add(new User(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString())); //add new user: id and image url
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify data set changed after adding each user (Not very efficient, huh?)
           }
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
           }
          };
          userKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
      }
      catch (JSONException e) { Log.d(TAG, "message " + e); }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil).

It uses an efficient algorithm to calculate the difference between your lists. And the cherry on the top is that this can be run on a background thread.

It is an alternative to `notifyDataSetChanged()` and is sort of an industry standard way for updating your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Any idea how to apply this to my code? It's troublesome because of the fact that I'm using for loop inside try catch block, and some things are out of scope of each other. would love to see a working example on my code

Comment: @Stackpile You can implement your own DiffUtil class to your adapter and whenever you receive a new list from the server you can simply call adapter.submitList(). It will automatically calculate the difference and apply the change to the UI.  [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) you can see an example of how to use it.

Comment: The problem is not only the list, you see in my code, for each id in the list i need to do a Firebase callback, so it's mixed and I have problems applying it to my code

Comment: Any idea how to mix it with my dynamically changing list? concrete solution? I can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Cloud functions.Pass the JSON Array to cloud function and retrieve the updated dataset in one go and notify the recycle view Here is [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)